# How to make a slow but powerful futuristic bow and arrow

Tags: physics, space, weapons, far-future

Obviously, guns are pretty superior to bows and arrows, nearly no matter how good you make a bow (within realistic measures). But in this case, I need a weapon that can have a slow projectile that can be tracked with the eye (it doesn't have to be super slow, but it does need to be traceable by the eye).

I figure a depleted uranium arrow or something similarly dense would be needed to achieve good impact force when a slower speed is required. As for the bow itself, it would need to be relatively easy to draw, yet still have good release velocity. I think that's possible with some pulleys or mechanisms that "activate" at full draw, creating a greater pullback after reaching full draw, but I don't know the specifics.

In any case, I'm wondering the specifics to making a bow and arrow (or similar projectile-launching device) that is traceable with the eyes, yet viable in terms of potential damage. If there's a better solution, I'm open to it. A bow and arrow is preferable, but not necessarily the only viable answer. If more info is needed, lemme know.

Comment: What goal do you *aim* to achieve with your slow arrow/bow? If you want a powerful weapon that is traceable by bare eyes you could go for grenades or mortar shells...

Comment: The transfer of power to the projectile is dependent upon the length of contact between the propulsive force and the projectile. That's why shorter barreled guns pack less force (up until a certain point) than longer barreled ones, and PARTLY why shortbows are less powerful than longbows. Just make a bow with an exceedingly long draw like a ballista... though it wouldn't be usable by a single individual, since the longbow is pretty much at the human limit for the length of the draw. Useful Example: http://cad-comic.com/comic/the-campaign-into-the-fire-3/

Comment: @dot_Sp0T, the idea is that one could use portals or something similar to allow the arrow to change directions. A grenade is viable, but the fuses are often more approximate than exact. A mortar shell may be a bit excessive in close ranges. So a grenade is definitely viable, but more accuracy over area is desired.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, thanks for the info. Sadly, a ballista wouldn't work as this is desired to be used by an individual.

Comment: Then I'm not sure you can reach the tradeoff you're looking for - you're better off going Green Arrow/Hawkeye and attaching an explosive to the head of the arrow rather than trying to get a high impact from a low speed projectile. I will note that arrows CAN be tracked by the naked eye over long distances...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Why attach an explosive when you could use the classic boxing glove instead?

Comment: @KSmarts Lol... Boxing gloves aren't aerodynamic, silly...

Comment: If we're allowing "rips in space" as far future tech, then you can make the draw distance (and projectile) arbitrarily long...

Comment: Tracer rounds from modern firearms are 'observable' in that you can see the flight path. Do you need to see the flight path or do you need to see the actual projectile as it is flying through the air?

Comment: you could try some sort of "rubbery" material that makes more of a snap than traditional bow and arrow. A dense material for the arrow that is really good at keeping off wind resistance. Explosions. You could also add something like an "auto aim" feature to the bow (not sure if you want it better in usage or just damage). You could make it do different things such as an arrow with EMP's, arrow with that splits into dense shards of material, arrow that entraps in some sort of hardening material (green arrow esq). Or you could add some sort of feeding device for arrows

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Shorter barreled guns don't change the amount of propellant used.  They release their projectiles sooner, and therefore have less distance whereby to impart spin — if they are rifled.  With shotguns, it is a little different, but the longer barrels also do lengthen the effective range because the trajectories of the pellets are more coherent.  Sorry if I misunderstood you; I don't know all that much about gun technology.

Comment: @can-ned_food I was referring to force, not range. The same ammunition used in a shorter barrel will have less pressure pushing behind the bullet since it exits the barrel earlier. Of course accuracy is affected by rifling as well.

Answer (score 9):

> As for the bow itself, it would need to be relatively easy to draw, yet still have good release velocity.

This requirement categorically rules out bows (as well as weapons operating under similar principles, like slingshots), because the energy contained in an arrow is entirely supplied by the user's strength. Powerful bows require strong wielders and practice to effectively exert that strength.

There's a technology contemporary to bows that alleviated this.

**Crossbows**

Specifically, [Arbalests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbalest) get around the issue of being limited to the user's ability to exert force by distributing that force with a winch. Using modern or science-fictional materials, you can have an arbalest with a very favorable gear ratio that can store a tremendous amount of energy while being easy to wind. The downside is that the easier it is to wind, the longer it will take to do so.

However, regardless of how this arrow or bolt is launched, your fundamental problem is that a slow-moving, heavy projectile is not effective as a weapon. Kinetic energy is linearly proportional to mass, but quadratically proportional to velocity. Higher velocities also increase range and accuracy, requiring less compensation for gravity.

For reference, where hunting bows tend to have [around 50ftlbs](http://bestcompoundbowsource.com/compound-bow-kinetic-energy/) of energy, common 9mm handgun ammunition has [around 300ftlbs](http://www.ballistics101.com/9mm.php), giving it much greater range and armor-piercing ability. In order for this slow projectile to be a practical weapon in a sci-fi context, it needs to derive its killing power from something other than its kinetic energy. Thankfully, we already have the perfect solution.

**Grenade Launcher**

Or a derivative. A 40mm grenade launched from a [handheld launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M79_grenade_launcher) travels at about 75m/s, comparable to crossbows, while being easy to load and fire and having softer recoil than its caliber would suggest. A variety of projectile types are available, ranging from dumb slugs (training rounds) to high-explosive to HEAT to buckshot to flechettes.

If a single-shot weapon isn't effective enough, try [pump-action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Lake_grenade_launcher) or [revolving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milkor_MGL). You can deliver a much higher practical rate of fire than a bow, with much greater lethal potential.

Comment: Very good points. I suppose a projectile really has to be fast to be effective, unless explosives are used. I guess I'll need to take a different approach. This has been quite informative.

Comment: How does it categorically rule out bows?  I'm a self professed weakling, but even I can draw a 30lb bow and have a hope of an accurate shot.  With a compound bow,  someone like me could draw something much more powerful.  Add to this that a slug from a firearm is blunt, while a broadhead arrow point is very sharp.  It will easily penetrate ballistic armor as long as it doesn't hit the shock plate

Comment: @PaulTIKI A 30lb bow is not a battlefield weapon. Significantly stronger bows than that had difficulty piercing plate armor during the Renaissance, even using bodkin points as opposed to broadhead. If you want a more powerful bow, you physically need to supply more energy in the draw, and that works against 'relatively easy to draw' as the OP specified.

Comment: @Catgut you are correct about a 30lb bow.  However, a 75lb compound bow with a 70% drop off (to 23lbs) could be used by people like me. The difficulty comes in holding the string until you shoot which is why the compound bow is attractive.  With a long draw length and heavy arrow, someone like me could drop an Elk.  We don't know exactly what kinds of armor we are facing, but if it's modern ballistic body armor a broadhead will go through unless it hits a strike plate.  Bodkin arrows may have had problems with full on plate armor, but less difficulty with leather and chainmail

Comment: @PaulTIKI The utility of a bow against soft body armor is a reflection of the fact that bows are considered irrelevant to modern combat, so soft armor is not designed to resist arrow penetration. Soft armor similarly is not resistant to knives, but I don't see that as a compelling reason to take a knife to a gunfight, and ceramic body armor will stop an arrow cold. Even leaving armor-piercing ability aside, a 75lb compound bow has a quarter the muzzle energy of a handgun. That means much shorter range, and less terminal impact. A .22 can kill an elk too, but I wouldn't take one into combat.

Comment: All true.  The thing I keep coming back to is the requirement for the projectile to be followed by the naked eye.  After re-reading the question, I'm not even certain that we are dealing with a modern time-frame.  Also, are we dealing with something necessarily for large scale combat, or is it an exotic assasins weapon?  That's why I (personally) wouldn't rule out a compound bow.

Comment: It does not categorically rule out bows. It might PRACTICALLY rule them out. Just like there is no limit to the amount of weight a person can lift on the other end of a see-saw, there is no fixed upper limit for the ratio of projectile speed to strength required to draw the bow. If you think you've reached a limit, you can increase it by a different pulley system and pulling the bow back further. Eventually the you will be hindered by the curvature of the earth stopping you from pulling the bow back further (solution, very high heeled shoes) or the ocean (solution, boat).

Answer (score 4):

You projectile needs to be heavy to slow it down. Your impact will be:

```
F s = 1/2 m v^2 
F - force
s - slowdown distance
m - mass 
v - velocity
```

Since we are talking bow and arrow here, we can disregard the slowdown distance (assuming it's always the same, something close to 0), therefore to keep the force the same but lower the speed you need to increase the mass of the projectile.
Obviously this becomes untrackable pretty quickly since the speed is squared.

Say you want to cut  your speed by a factor of ten, from 10 to 1.
F initial = 1/2 m * 10^2 = 1/2 *m *100 = 50m 
F desired = 1/2 m * 1^2 = 1/2 * m * 1 = 1/2 m

So to cut your speed from 10 to 1 (whatever units), you need to increase your mass 100 times.

Physics dictates you have to move fast to deliver a punch.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are shooting at, but Modern compound bows will meet your needs as stated.

There are a number of things an archer has to consider when doing the bow and arrow thing.  Each contribute to how the arrow is going to perform.

First thing everyone thinks of is the bow.  Draw weight and draw length determine a lot of how fast the arrow is going to go.  Long draw length means the arrow is accelerating for a longer period and Draw weight is how much force is being applied to the arrow.  In this question a compound bow (with pulleys) is mentioned, so we can go with that.  For a normal human male around 1.8 m tall (6 feet or so) the recommended draw length from a compound bow is about 29 inches.  The Draw weight can be anywhere from 15lbs for kids up to 75lbs for burly, manly men.  A good guideline would be around a 40 to 50lb draw weight, because that's what is usually recommended for  hunting medium to large game like deer.  Here is where a compund bow has an advantage though, once you get to a certain point, it "lets off", meaning what it takes to hold the drawn bow is much less than the full draw weight.  A 50lb bow with a 70% let off means you only have to hold 15lbs on target creating greater accuracy.

Next, the weight of your arrow.  This has 2 influences on what you can do, Momentum and Energy.  The Energy is how hard the arrow hits initially, but Momentum is how far that arrow will carry through the target.  A light arrow is faster, and therefore has more energy, but a heavy arrow will have more momentum.

Next you have to consider the arrowhead.  Simple target points are fairly blunt while Broadheads consist of multiple razor sharp blades.  There are a variety of other types but these are the most common.  You aren't going to kill a deer with a blunt tip even with a light arrow with a heavy draw, there isn't enough momentum to penetrate.  A slower moving heavy arrow with a razor broadhead will cut through deep enough for a clean kill.

You can then combine these things to have a weapons system capable of bringing down Moose, Cape Buffalo, or just about anything else on the planet from a couple hundred yards, at least.

Other answers have mentioned explosives.  Add impact or proximity based explosives for even more fun and carnage.  These would be lightweight affairs, but they would have enough power to splatter everything in a small sphere.  This mitigates the semi randomness a timed fuse might have.

Comment: While a modern "manly man" can draw a 75lb bow, Medieval English and Welsh longbowmen were able to handle draw weights of 100 to 120lbs with no "let off" and shoot fast enough to create arrow storms. Steel crossbows using spanning mechanisms could have draw weights of 1200lbs, and this was barely adequate against plate armour. Anything which can fire a DU "arrow" would need a huge draw weight to generate any sort of range or impact velocity.

Comment: @Thucydides  This is where the importance of the tip comes in.  A modern broadhead arrow does not need to penetrate very deep to cause an awful lot of damage.  imagine getting 3 or 4 inch long boxcutter blades just past your ribcage, all angled in one direction to prevent being pulled back out.  I also understand that Bodkin arrows were also useful at penetrating armor to a point.  Though they weren't necessarily lethal, they could cause wounds

Answer (score 3):

Slings are even less futuristic than arrows.

[image]

http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1168&context=nebanthro

A sling projectile travels more slowly than an arrow.  But slings get the job done very well, and rocks are a lot cheaper than arrows.  The reference for this table has some good back reading. The table shows the damage done as you increase projectile weight and speed.  A normal arrow is about 90 m/s and so the fastest sling speed here was still slower; from the reference normal sling speed is probably 40 m/2.

[image]

You could scale it up, with heavier projectiles.  With a really heavy projectile you need a counterweight as you spin it up to speed.  Hammer throwers use their bodies as the counterweight.
[image]

It occurs to me that if you want to throw a very heavy projectile, you might be better off throwing a group of lighter projectiles.  The cloud will spread out in flight.  It will be less easy to step out of the way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You get power from speed and mass.  If you decrease the speed,  you have to increase the mass.  This is OK if you are targeting a satellite or other non moving object.  In fact the increased mass may mitigate countermeasures since it will take more force to knock the weapon off course.

However, if the target can maneuver and can see the weapon (or just knows it is in danger and is moving randomly), you will likely not hit it.

A slow moving massive object cannot be used in a strong gravity well unless the target is at the bottom of the gravity well.  Shooting a slow & heavy from a bow on Earth will result in an arrow hitting the ground not far from you.  However, dropping a crowbar from orbit onto a building on the Earth will be quite effective.

Comment: True. Would it be possible to utilize a computer tracker (say, in a helmet) to give the user a visual to track the projectile despite a higher speed?

Comment: It would be incredibly easy to track.  That's the problem.  The target can (figuratively speaking) just take a step to the side or avoid it.

Comment: Right. Sry, I meant could it be sped up to make it difficult to avoid (or track with just the eyes), but still traceable by perhaps aided means (such as a computer tracker).

Comment: @Iter, yes.  That would give it the other advantages of speed.  Tracking it from the launcher will be no problem since you can calculate it's path.  You don't need to see it.  Tracking it is kind of pointless though.  As a projectile, it cannot course correct.  Even if you turned it into a missile and put some kind of maneuvering thrusters on it, its mass would make it very difficult to move from its current path.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a superior bow and arrow.

You need *superior archers*.

[image]

If you replace the limbs of your commandos with powerful, enhanced prosthetics and enhance their torso with more resistant materials and synthetic muscles, you can end up with archers that put *way* more power into each shot, using bows with far higher draw strength and heavier arrows.

Alternative, if mutilating your soldiers for the Greater Good(tm) isn't an option, you can go the power armor route:

[image]

This has the added benefit being.. not so silly, when compared to battle prosthetics, and also doubling as very powerful armor.

Answer (score 1):

While the question as asked does not seem to have a reasonable answer, I would suggest that (assuming firearms are not allowed) torsion based weapons might be considered rather than tension weapons like bows.

Ancient *ballista* were designed to transfer the draw energy into skeins of rope or sinew, which could then store the energy for a short time while the crew loaded and aimed the weapon. Ballista could range in size from Roman Scorpions, which would be analogous to a modern crew served machine gun, to massive devices for flinging stones at enemy fortifications.

[image]

*Seige Ballista*

[image]

*Scorpion*

Like crossbows, they have slow rates of fire, given the need to mechanically draw the device, and they eventually fell out of use due to the expense of building them and the need for experienced engineers to build and maintain them (the skeins of rope or sinew needed constant attention, since stretching due to weather or overuse would reduce the performance  of the device. It is also thought that the larger devices would be built on the spot using local materials, with the engineers only providing critical metal components for assembling and tensioning the skeins).

While it seems possible to build a torsion powered device the size of a man portable crossbow, it will be very expensive compared to a steel crossbow with a similar draw weight, so it is hard to see what the advantage is at that scale. A scorpion could throw a javelin far longer and harder than any human being, which was the big advantage for Roman armies, but even then, the expense of such devices caused them to disappear from the Roman armoury after the crisis of the Third Century, if not before.

[image]

*A ballista shrunk to hand held scale*

Counterpoise devices like the trebuchet have similar issues with size, speed of action and requiring talented engineering crews to build and operate.

[image]

*Trebuchet. An example of a counterpoise device*

Frankly, the requirement to see the round in flight can be far more easily achieved by using a tracer on the end of the round. Tank crews use tracers to observe the fall of shot when firing APDS-FS rounds at 1200 m/sec, which would seem to meet your need for a DU "arrow"...

[image]

*120mm APDS-FS round. You **can** see this in flight as the tank gunner...*